# Solving recurrence equation with generating indices of positive indices

Tags: calculus, functions, discrete-mathematics

I don't know how to solve recurrence equation with positive indices like $$a_{n+2}  + 4a_{n+1}+
4a_n = 7$$ by generating functions.
How to solve such kind of problems.

Comment: Solving Eigenvalues

Comment: I don't know the procedure to solve such kind of problems ,I have solved similar problems with negative indices but not this type of problems

Comment: If you know how to solve with negative indices, just wrtie $b_{n+2} = a_n$ and you have your recurrence equation with negative indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** You may just multiply both sides of the following relation by $x^{n+2}$ and summing it:
$$
a_{n+2}  + 4a_{n+1}+4a_n = 7 \tag1
$$ to get
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n+2}x^{n+2}  + 4x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n+1}x^{n+1}+4x^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n= 7x^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n
$$ or
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}  + 4x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}+4x^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n= 7x^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n \tag2
$$ equivalently, setting $\displaystyle f(x):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n} $, you formally get 
$$
f(x)-a_0-a_1x+4x(f(x)-a_0)+4x^2f(x)=7x^2\frac{1}{1-x} 
$$ that is
$$
(2x+1)^2f(x)=\frac{7x^2}{1-x}+(4a_0+a_1)x+a_0
$$
$$
f(x)=\frac{7x^2}{(1-x)(2x+1)^2}+\frac{(4a_0+a_1)x+a_0}{(2x+1)^2} \tag3
$$ Then by **partial fraction decomposition** and **power series expansion**, you are able **to identify** coefficients of both sides of $(3)$.

Comment: (+1) I like the generating function approach. Since you have given that, I gave the difference equation approach.

Answer (score 1):

**A Special Class of Recurrence Equations**

To solve the homogenous recurrence
$$
(S-\lambda)^ka_n=0\tag{1}
$$
where $Sa_n=a_{n+1}$ is a shift operator, we note that if $a_n=\lambda^n b_n$ then $S^k(\lambda^nb_n)=(\lambda S)^kb_n$. Therefore, $(1)$ becomes $(\lambda S-\lambda)^kb_n=0$, which is equivalent to
$$
(S-1)^kb_n=0\tag{2}
$$
$(2)$ says that the $k^{\text{th}}$ forward difference of $b_n$ vanishes. That is, $b_n$ is a $k-1$ degree polynomial in $n$, which means that the solution to $(1)$ is
$$
a_n=\lambda^n\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}c_jn^j\tag{3}
$$

---

**Particular and Homogenous Solutions**

A particular solution to $a_{n+2}+4a_{n+1}+4a_n=7$ is
$$
a_n=\frac79\tag{4}
$$
The homogeneous equation $a_{n+2}+4a_{n+1}+4a_n=0$ is simply $(S+2)^2a_n=0$, and according to the preceding section, we get the solution to be
$$
a_n=(c_0+c_1n)(-2)^n\tag{5}
$$
Putting the particular and homogeneous solutions together gives
$$
a_n=\frac79+(c_0+c_1n)(-2)^n\tag{6}
$$
Now we just need to determine $c_0$ and $c_1$ to satisfy whatever other conditions we have.

Comment: Very clean! (+1).

Answer (score 0):

To make your life easier start with the difference equation to get rid of the constant. You get (set $b_n = a_n - a_{n-1}$):

$$
b_{n+2} =-4 b_{n+1} - 4 b_n
$$

Now use GF.

EDIT
$$
a_{n+2} +4 a_{n+1} + 4 a_n = 7\\
a_{n+1} + 4 a_{n} +4 a_{n-1} = 7\\
\Delta a_{n+2} +4 \Delta a_{n+1} + 4 \Delta a_n = 0
$$
Now set $\Delta a_n = b_n$ and use GF.

Comment: I am not getting you.

Comment: OK, See the edit